# Is there a way to eliminate redundant clauses in first-order logic?

Tags: first-order-logic

I'm new to mathematical logic and wondering is there a way to eliminate redundant clauses in first order logic.

Here is an example of my question: given two knowledge bases each containing a first-order sentence, say
\begin{gather*}
KB_1=∃x_1, x_2, x_3\colon P(x_1, x_2)∧T(x_2, x_3)\\
KB_2=∃x_1, x_2, x_3\colon P(x_1, x_2)∧R(x_2, x_3)
\end{gather*}
now the task is to merge the two knowledge bases into one KB. My designed code tries to do this by simply adding up these two KBs and renaming the variables, and the result will be
$$KB=∃x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5, x_6\colon P(x_1, x_2)∧T(x_2, x_3)∧P(x_4, x_5)∧R(x_5, x_6)$$
Seems fine but if the KBs are identical, say
$$KB_1=KB_2=∃x_1, x_2, x_3\colon P(x_1, x_2)∧T(x_2, x_3)$$
the result will be
$$KB=∃x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5, x_6\colon P(x_1, x_2)∧T(x_2, x_3)∧P(x_4, x_5)∧T(x_5, x_6)$$
which is obviously redundant since the first two clauses are the same as the last two clauses, so I wonder if there is a formal way to do redundancy elimination in this kind of situation, thanks!

Comment: Yes $P \land P \equiv P$

Comment: @Mauro ALLEGRANZA Hi, thanks for your answer, but sorry I don't quite get what you mean...